# Declare property getter in parent interface and setter in child interface in c#

Tags: c#

I want to declare the *getter* of a property in a parent interface and the *setter* in the child interface:

```
    public interface IReadOnlyValue
    {
        int Value { get; }
    }
    public interface IValue : IReadOnlyValue
    {
        int Value { set; }
    }
    public class Value : IValue 
    {
        int Value { get; set; }
    }
```

This **doesn't compile** because the `Value` from `IValue` `hides` the one from `IReadOnlyValue`. Is there a way to make this work, knowing that I need `Value` to be a *property*?

Comment: In what case would you need an `IValue` and an `IReadOnlyValue` ? Surely you'd want one or the other but not both? a way around it would be to create a `IReadOnlyValue` interface with a `int GetValue { get; } ` property and a `ISetOnlyValue` interface with a `int SetValue { set; } ` property?

Comment: This is for viewmodel observables in Xaml. I want to hide the setter for OneWay bindings and expose it for TwoWay ones while keeping the same implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it's a *class name* `Value` that's wrong:

> Error CS0542  'Value': **member names** cannot be the **same** as their
>   **enclosing type**

(bold is mine). If you rename `Value` to, say, `MyValue` it'll be OK:

```
  public interface IReadOnlyValue {
    int Value { get; }
  }

  // It seems that IValue should have both "get" and "set"
  // See IList<T> and IReadOnlyList<T> as an example
  // However, you can drop "get" if you want
  public interface IValue {
    int Value { get; set; }
  }

  public class MyValue: IReadOnlyValue, IValue {
    public int Value { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: Cool stuff, I didn't know the implementation would be able to implement both interfaces with the same property. Thanks!

Comment: @Friedrik - And if you absolutely want `IValue` to inherit `IReadOnlyValue`, so you could for example use any `IValue` anywhere you'd need an `IReadOnlyValue`, you could make use of the `new` keyword and define it like `public interface IValue : IReadOnlyValue { new int Value { get; set; } }`, which might feel a bit weird, buit works pretty well. (`MyValue` then needs to implement "just" `IValue`)